# How to filter out different classes into an array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How will I take product with same category into a string or an array?

```html
<ul>
  <li class="product_cat-category-1"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-3"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-2"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-5"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-1"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-2"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-3"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-5"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-4"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-1"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-2"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-3"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-4"></li>
</ul>
```

What I want exactly is to filter them and append them into a new div to create a filterable animation using GSAP. This is actually a WordPress WooCommerce product page.

Last time I created a popup using GSAP, and in that I used something called split() function:

```js
triggers.each(function(){
    let listClassName = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
    let revealClassName = String(listClassName[listClassName.indexOf(listClassName.find(element => element === 'dasrgsap__reveal-trigger')) + 1]);
    const sectionReveal = $('.dasrgsap__reveal-content.' + revealClassName);
    const colReveal = $('.dasrgsap__reveal-content.' + revealClassName + ' .et_pb_column');
});
```

The trigger was (`dasrgsap__reveal-trigger sandra`) and the popup content container was (`dasrgsap__reveal-container sandra`). Both were given two separate classes, which made it easier to split and access them.

In this case, WooCommerce product list items are given too many classes, so the only class I can play with to get a specific category is the `product_cat-'product-category'`.

I want to get a string or array of the same product category, and I want to split `product_cat-` and `category-1` and get an array of that category, but I'm not able to do it.

Is this even possible?

Comment: could you please clarify a bit more? What exactly should the end result look like? Example of that array structure. And what have you tried so far on your own to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is only a guess but is this what you were after

```js
$("li").each(function() {
  var category = $.makeArray(
    $(this)
    .attr("class")
    .slice(
      $(this).attr("class").indexOf("-") + 1,
      $(this).attr("class").length
    )
  );
  // console.log(category);

  var product = $.makeArray($(this)
    .attr("class")
    .slice(0, $(this).attr("class").indexOf("-")))
  // console.log(category);

  var completeList = $.merge(product, category);
  console.log(completeList)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="product_cat-category-1"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-3"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-2"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-5"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-1"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-2"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-3"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-5"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-4"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-1"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-2"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-3"></li>
  <li class="product_cat-category-4"></li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7xcpjr59/

I hope it helps

Comment: hi, thanks for this, but its giving array of 2 things i.e product_cat and category-1, what I'm trying to achive is to make an array of all the same category products, i want  five different array of cantainge products of each category

Comment: the $.merge(product, category); will match each product_cat with its corresponding category- item, you could easily alter this to group by or use a foreach / map method and some if conditions to build a jagged array. I don't understand what your looking for, if you could write an example of the array result you are after even if its hard coded or sudo code that would help